# How to check the return type of a generic method to prevent NPE when unboxing

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, return-type, autoboxing

Consider the following code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

/**
 *
 * @author Colby
 */
public class Entity {

    //test code
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Entity e = new Entity();

        e.put("username", "colby");
        e.put("level", 99);
        e.put("hours played", Long.MAX_VALUE - 1);
        e.put("banned", true);

        String username = e.get("username");
        int level = e.get("level");
        long played = e.get("hours played");
        boolean banned = e.get("banned");

        System.out.println(username);
        System.out.println(level);
        System.out.println(played);
        System.out.println(banned);
    }

    public Entity() {
        map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    private final Map<String, Object> map;

    public <T> void put(String key, T value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    public <T> T get(String key) {
        return (T) map.get(key);
    }

    public boolean has(String key) {
        return get(key) != null;
    }
}
```

A very useful properties system. Now my problem comes when I do something like this:

```
int i = e.get("non existent key");
```

The map get will return null, and thus will throw a NPE on unboxing.

My attempted solution was:

```
public <T> T get(String key) {
    Object o = map.get(key);
    if(o == null) {
        if(T instanceof Integer) {
            return (T) new Integer(-1);
        }
    }
    return (T) o;
}
```

However, I get an error cannot find symbol T on the instanceof line. How could I improve this code?

Comment: The unboxing won't happen in the `get`. Your error occurs because the left hand side of `instanceof` needs to be an reference value expression, not a type. Use `o instanceof Integer`. Get rid of the `== null`. `instanceof` already validates against `null`.

Comment: The unboxing will occur if you try to assign the result of `get` to a primitive variable.

Comment: @Pillar If o == null then it will not be instanceof Integer and thus the method will return null and throw NPE on the line "int i = get..."

Comment: `if (o instanceof Integer)` then return `o`. If it's not, then return some default value that isn't `null`, if you want to prevent the NPE.

Comment: @Pillar Yes I understand. However is the only solution just to have a separate get method for ints? Seems clunky.

Comment: @Pillar What kind of default value could I use that would not throw NPE when assigning to a primitive and ClassCastException if I try to pass an Integer as some other object? That is what I'm asking. How can I determine the needed return type of the method?

Comment: That's the problem with using generic type inference to resolve a value from a map that can hold anything. For the NPE, have your client code use `Integer`, not `int`.

Comment: @Pillar To clarify, if I use "-1" as the default return value, it will work for ints. But not for booleans. So It needs multiple possible return types. How can I check the real return type at runtime? Using Integer is just clunky and defeats the entire point of the map, ease of use.

Comment: This method won't work particularly well anyway - regardless of the `Integer` bit in the middle - unless `map.get(key)` happens to be an instance of `T`. But you could call `entity.<String>get("hello")` and `entity.<StringBuilder>get("hello")`, and only one would work without a `ClassCastException` (unless, I suppose, `map.get("hello") == null`).

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes that is expected behavior. The client will know the return type of the key before calling get, so there is no issue here except for when using primitives. Creating an integer and then checking if that integer is null before using every time would defeat the purpose of the code.

Comment: @ColbyMcDowell if the client knows the type, there's no problem with having separate methods then.

Comment: There is no nice way to do this. Avoid it if possible. http://www.codeaffine.com/2015/03/04/map-distinct-value-types-using-java-generics/

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the default value as an argument to your method.

```
public <T> T get(String key, T defaultValue) {
    Object o = map.get(key);
    if(o == null) {
        return defaultValue;
    } else {
        return (T) o;
    }
}
```

Comment: And in Java 8 you can use getOrDefault method of Map interface

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a key which contains the type information as well as the label:

```
abstract class Key<T> {
  private final String label;
  private final T defaultValue;

  Key(String label, T defaultValue) {
    // Assign to fields.
  }

  T defaultValue() { return defaultValue; }

  @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // Implement to check both label and getClass().
  }

  @Override public int hashCode() {
    // Implement to check both label and getClass().
  }
}
```

Then use this instead of the plain `String`:

```
public <T> void put(Key<T> key, T value) {
  map.put(key, value);
}

public <T> T get(Key<T> key) {
  if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
    return key.defaultValue();
  } else {
    return (T) map.get(key);
  }
}
```

You'd then instantiate `Key` instances like:

```
Key<String> fooKey = new Key<String>("Foo", "someDefaultValue") {};
Key<Integer> barKey = new Key<Integer>("Bar", -1) {};
Key<List<String>> listKey = new Key<List<String>>("List", new ArrayList<String>()) {};
```

This allows you to codify the client's knowledge of the type associated with the key. The cast in `get` is safe because you know that only entries of the correct type have been put into the map.